# Why is my iAd banner not showing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, iad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = adFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];

}


- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {

        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a four things.  First, you should be positioning the banner off screen in your viewDidLoad method because it will just show an empty frame when you first launch and will more than likely get rejected because of it.

Secondly, you are setting up your banner view incorrectly.  I think the frame is still CGZero.  Thirdly you are not setting the bannerView's delegate.  Try the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CGRect frame=CGRectZero;
    frame.size = [ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    // Place frame at the bottom edge of the screen out of sight
    frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds));

    // Now to create and configure the banner view
    ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    // Set the delegate to self, so that we are notified of ad responses
    adView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview: adView];
}
```

Fourth, in your bannerViewDidLoadAd: method you are not animating the banner ad into place.  Try this:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    // Get a brand new frame
    CGRect newFrame=CGRectZero;
    CGPoint frameOrigin=CGPointZero;
    // Set the origin
    frameOrigin=CGPointMake(0.0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds));
    newFrame.origin=frameOrigin;

    // Set the size
    newFrame.size=[ADBannerView sizeFromBannerContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];

    CGFloat bannerHeight = newFrame.size.height;
    CGFloat bannerOffset=0.0;

    // Determine where the new frame should be
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {   
        // It should be visible, raise it up
        bannerOffset=-bannerHeight;
    }

    CGRect offSetRect=CGRectOffset(newFrame,0.0f,bannerOffset);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{banner.view.frame=offSetRect}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (bannerOffSet<0){
                               self.bannerIsVisible=YES;
                             }else{
                               self.bannerIsVisible=NO;
                             }
                         }
        ]; 

}
```

of course if the banner is supposed to be positioned at the top of the screen, you can probably figure out how things need to be modified, but this gets you in going in the right direction.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Not sure by reading your question, but do be aware that Apple simulates iAds not being available.  Sometimes you need to try multiple times before the sample ad comes through.